# HttpClient Post - Not getting response in Xamarin

Tags: android, http, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been struggling with an issue for almost two days now.

I have a Xamarin.Android application which is referencing a .NET standard library I have written for data access. The class library consumes two API's. 
One is an external API though mashape. This works fine.

However, when consuming the other API, which I developed on hosted on a local instance of IIS, the HTTP requests never complete and the application hangs. The local API has been tested on POSTMAN and also consumed through a console application and is working.

The IIS logs show that the Console application connects successfully but not the app.

The code is below.

```
 public bool registerUser(RegisterUseModel model)
    {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(APIurl);
        builder.Append("User/Register");
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        Task<string> response = postRequest<RegisterUseModel>(builder.ToString(), model);                            
        bool value = JsonConverter.getSingleResult<bool>(response.Result);

        return value;
    }


 public async Task<string> postRequest<T>(string uri, T data)
    {

        var contents = "";
        string jsonBody = JsonConverter.toJsonSingle<T>(data);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {


            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                uri,
                new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                );

            contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return contents;

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you recived request on this local IIS server after send it from app?

Comment: No, when the request is made from the Console, it is registered in the logs. But no requests from the app are logged. I've edited the question appropriately. 
Thanks

Comment: So i understand that you didnt test this code directly from phone ? If so try to install fiddler and check what actually is sending

Comment: I have tested it from a phone. The application gets stuck when making the HTTP request using HttpClient.

Comment: It's strange cuz httpclient got 100sec timeout so if request make your application stuck after this 100s it should throw timeout exception

Comment: Can u make `registerUser` async and awaited `postRequest` in it ?

Comment: `hosted on a local instance of IIS` You are not using `localhost` in your URL as a host name, are you?

Comment: I remember doing something similar once. One huge gotcha is the content-type header. If your IIS service is expecting (for example) JSON, and no content-type header is included, the application will hang. 

For debugging, I'd recommend installing Fiddler from Telerik and/or Wireshark and then monitoring connections to/from the device you're developing on/for.